# C shell issue with undefined variable

Tags: shell, tcsh

I'm learning some shell scripting using the tcsh shell. 
My program should calculate multiplication table for range of 2 first arguments. If first arg is bigger than second it should print it from the bigger to smaller. But instead of this he is working correctly if I give him first arg bigger than second. But while I'm giving him first arg smaller I have the: "d: Undefined variable" error.

```
if ( $argv[1] > $argv[2] ) then
while ($argv[1] >= $argv[2])
    foreach y ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )
        @ d = ( $argv[1] * $y )
        if ( $d < 10 )then
            echo -n " $d "
        else
            echo -n "$d "
        endif
    end
    echo "\n"
    @ argv[1] -= 1
end
exit 0
else
while ($argv[1] <= $argv[2])
    foreach y ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )
        @ c = ( $argv[1] * $y )
        if ( $c < 10 )then
            echo -n " $c "
        else
            echo -n "$c "
        endif
    end
    echo "\n"
    @ argv[1] += 1
end
exit 0
endif
```

If I switch if and else (first will be part responsible for arg1 smaller than arg2) It works fine for arg1 smaller than arg2, but not in opposite situation with "c: Undefined variable" error.

Could you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: change your "she-bang" line to `#!/.../tcsh -vx` so you can see the debug/trace. Then you may be able to see which line is causing the problem. (put correct path to instead of `/.../` of course). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really stupid mistake: I forget about space before then and "else" from second loop was taken to the first loop.

Comment: https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to declare variable by set command

```
set var = value ;
```

Comment: But now in this line"

Comment: Ok, but when I am doing it and I will print echo "$d" I get not only the number, but some kind of file too (like documents, music, images etc).

Comment: no idea :/ sorry 
for me set worked for c case but for d still undefined variable !!

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi : you use the form `set var = value` for string values. To set variables so you can use them as integers, you need to use the form `@ num = 8`. Good luck to all.